# How to pre populate fields in Salesforc1?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using VF page to show Lightning component on it. Using URL hack to prepopulate fields. This works perfect in Salesforce, however it does not in Salesforce1

Comment: are you want to do this in Standard page or custom page

Answer (score 1):

Dont use url hack. Just pass the values in url

And get all the values in VF page controller using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('your param');`

Assign this value to any field that you want to prepopulate.

Use for multiple fields

Comment: What if it is a standard account create page where we are using URL hack. is there a way to get fields pre populated?

Comment: @KaushikRay yes for standard account create page you can use url hack to pre-populate the fields..

Comment: but with lightning layout it does not work as mentioned http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117208/lightning-url-hack-issue-with-prepopulating-fields-on-page-load and https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.salesforce.com%2Fforums%2F%3Fid%3D906F0000000ML5eIAG&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNF_dDrENeCJMMMdPS1yo7PFbaVSPw

Comment: @KaushikRay no this is not applicable for lightning. ONly in classic layout we can use url hack and prepopulate the values..

Comment: Thanks sfdcweb. Just wondering if there is something that we can do for lightning to handle url hacks?

Comment: @KaushikRay salesforce team trining making there system so secure, using lightning they are already doing that..may be some day anyone find a solution to hack url can't say surely.. but there is always a possibility.. JUST for FYI: If you are using any lightning component then you can populate those component input field value using URL hack..