# Is URL hacking not possible in a nested lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, urlhacking

I have a search tool built out. I want the search bar to prepopulate with search terms from the URL, cant seem to get it to work though.

```
<aura:attribute name="searchVar" type="String"/>
<div class="slds" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;">
        <ui:inputText class="form-control" value="{!v.searchVar}"
                      placeholder="Search"/>
```

I was expecting to be able to populate using ..

```
/appname.app?searchVar=SearchTerms
```

Comment: check this post.. in lightning component you want populate value using url hack check this post... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117208/lightning-url-hack-issue-with-prepopulating-fields-on-page-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightning App - getting URL parameter](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106543/lightning-app-getting-url-parameter)

Comment: This will only work is the attribute is defined in the .app. What is I want to pass the parameter to a nested component?

Comment: Can you please update your question with desire requirement else it is marked as duplicate.  And Related to nested component I believe only solution to pass in url and assign to attribute another solution can be use javascript to get the values from url and assign it to any attribute etc...

Comment: As far I am thinking if your component is nested still you can assign the attribute value using url like above links ... Can you please try this once?

Comment: I tried, was not able to get it to work.

Comment: If URL hacking won't work in a lightning component to begin with, how are you expecting it to work in a nested component?

Comment: I can get it to work in a lightning "app", but cant pass the value to the nested component. But...thanks for the insight.